# Define '*.properties' file location in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have Spring context with several beans, like:

```
<bean id="anyBean" class="com.my.app.AnyBean"
   p:test_user="${any1}"
   p:test_pass="${any2}">
</bean>
```

To resolve these placeholders (${any1} and ${any2}) I use:

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" p:location="my.properties" />
```

It works fine, but I need to define location of the 'my.properties' from 'main' method of the main class. Like this:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(my_xml_config.xml);
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = context.getBean("propertyPlaceholderConfigurer", PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);

Resource resource = context.getResource("path/to/my.properties");
ppc.setLocation(resource);
```

But when I try to launch it:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name 'AnyBean' defined in class path
>   resource [my_xml_config.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'any1' in
>   string value "${any1}"

Could you hint is there any way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time you try to get a bean

```
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = context.getBean("propertyPlaceholderConfigurer", PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.class);
```

Spring has already tried to refresh your context and failed since the property isn't present. You need to prevent Spring from doing this by [specifying it in the constructor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html#ClassPathXmlApplicationContext-java.lang.String:A-boolean-)

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"my_xml_config.xml"}, false);
```

Since the `ApplicationContext` is not refreshed, the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean doesn't exist.

For this to work, you need to use a [`PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) instead of a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` (thanks M.Deinum). You can declare it in the XML in the same way as you did for the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` bean, or use

```
<context:property-placeholder />
```

You need to take advantage of the fact that `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` has its own locations, but also uses the `PropertySource` instances registered in the `ApplicationContext`'s `Environment`.

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"your_config.xml"}, false);
// all sorts of constructors, many options for finding the resource
ResourcePropertySource properties = new ResourcePropertySource("path/to/my.properties");
context.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(properties);
context.refresh();
```

Comment: The `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` doesn't consult the `PropertySource`s, the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` does. Instead of configuring the bean use the `<context:property-placeholder />` tag which defaults (in recent spring versions) to `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: @M.Deinum The OP wants to set the properties location programmatically. I guess `<context:property-placeholder />` is not an option.

Comment: And why not, you can still use the location property of that. Set the name of the file as a system property and spring will use that.

Comment: Should the PropertyPlaceHolderCongigurer stay in XML spring cofig?